# Ubuntu 18: Set usb mouse speed / sensitivity (panel and xinput not working)

Tags: usb, 18.04, mouse

Mousespeed was fine in Ubuntu 16.04. Since the upgrade the mouse is much too fast. How can I effectively change my mouse speed?

I know there is a "Mouse and Touchpad" panel. I don't know what it's there for. It never worked for me.

I also tried synclient, but that's only setting up the touchpad. Not the Mouse.

I don't want to change the acceleration value, as I can then not predict mouse behavior anymore.

I know there is xinput. But there is no appropriate option available for me anymore:

```
Device Enabled (142):   1
Coordinate Transformation Matrix (144): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (280):   0
libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (281):   0
libinput Scroll Methods Available (282):    0, 0, 1
libinput Scroll Method Enabled (283):   0, 0, 0
libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (284):   0, 0, 0
libinput Button Scrolling Button (285): 2
libinput Button Scrolling Button Default (286): 2
libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (287):    0
libinput Middle Emulation Enabled Default (288):    0
libinput Accel Speed (289): 0.000000
libinput Accel Speed Default (290): 0.000000
libinput Accel Profiles Available (291):    1, 1
libinput Accel Profile Enabled (292):   1, 0
libinput Accel Profile Enabled Default (293):   1, 0
libinput Left Handed Enabled (294): 0
libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (295): 0
libinput Send Events Modes Available (265): 1, 0
libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (266):    0, 0
libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (267):    0, 0
Device Node (268):  "/dev/input/event3"
Device Product ID (269):    1507, 4613
libinput Drag Lock Buttons (296):   <no items>
libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (297):   1
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue. I was able to fix it by changing the "Accel Speed" property in xinput. It didn't occur to me at first that it's possible to set negative values for it, but when I tried it I was happily surprised my mouse is now going slower again.

So full info, first type "xinput list" to get a list of devices, your mouse should be in the list:

```
~$ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Genius Optical Mouse                      id=8    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳   USB Keyboard                            id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳   USB Keyboard                            id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

In my output pasted above, my mouse has ID 8. We can use this to find the mouse properties:

```
~$ xinput list-props 8
Device 'Genius Optical Mouse':
    Device Enabled (148):   1
    <...snip...>
    libinput Accel Speed (294): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Speed Default (295): 0.000000
    <...snip...>
```

We find the property number for Accel Speed (294 in my case). We can use this to lower it below zero:

```
xinput set-prop 8 294 -0.5
```

Note you need to change the 8 with your mouse ID, and the 294 with your "Accel Speed" property number. I found -0.5 to be an acceptable value for me, but you might want to set it to something different.

To make this change permanent after reboot, you will need to run that command automatically at startup. I'm not sure how that works in vanilla Ubuntu, but with XFCE (Xubuntu) you can do "Settings -> Session and Startup -> Application Autostart -> Add" and then fill in the full xinput command as command, and a nice name and description.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I solved this by removing `libinput` and replacing it with `evdev`:

```
sudo apt remove xserver-xorg-input-libinput
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-evdev
```

This helped me.

Comment: I can't verify, as buying a new mouse, that would do those settings on hardware level solved the problem. For people reading this: `libinput` is supposed to be the future, while `evdev` is supposed to be the past.